# Падает приложение при вызове метода

Tags: java, android, kotlin

В моём layout'e вешаю onClick на кнопку, где прописываю ей метод countMe:

```
fun countMe(view: View) {

    // Get the value of the text view.
    val countString = textView.text.toString()

    // Convert value to a number and increment it
    var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
    count++

    // Display the new value in the text view.
    textView.text = count.toString();
}
```

После чего вылетает такая ошибка, kotlin extensions plugin подключен, также пробовал без него следующим образом:

```
fun countMe (view: View) {

// Get the text view
    val showCountTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView

    // Get the value of the text view.
    val countString = showCountTextView.text.toString()

    // Convert value to a number and increment it
    var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
    count++

    // Display the new value in the text view.
    showCountTextView.text = count.toString();
}
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.vadim.codelabfirstkotlinapp, PID: 2772
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Hello world"
       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
       at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
       at com.example.vadim.codelabfirstkotlinapp.MainActivity.countMe(MainActivity.kt:33)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

При изменении TextView

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
   android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Падает в данной строке кода

```
var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin тут не причём. Если вы посмотрите в логи ошибки то там будет конкретная причина - вы пытаетесь в число преобразовать строку `HelloWorld`

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Hello world"

Проверьте что и как вы передаёте в метод

```
Integer.parseInt(countString)
```

Comment: Возможно я что то неправильно понял из данного материала https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6 но по моему суть была в том, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку определить количество нажатий.

Comment: @Inkognito, ну... Проверьте разметку. Может у вас там для текстового поля указан текст, хотя не должен.

Comment: Почему не должен? Там же так раз ссылка на строковый ресурс. Или что там должно быть тогда?

Comment: @Inkognito, ну, видимо ссылка на ресурс с текстом `HelloWorld`. В итоге вы его пытаетесь в число преобразовать и неизбежно падаете. Просто удалить текст из текстового поля.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Inkognito, неинформативно. В текстовом поле у вас таки нет текста?! И падает там же? И с той же ошибкой. Не могу в это поверить

Comment: Ну так вы посоветовали удалить текст, вот я и удалил. Но ошибка да, такая же.

Comment: @Inkognito а поставьте тогда туда `android:text="0"`, ну так, чисто для проверки.

Comment: @Inkognito, прямо совсем такая же? Т.е. попытка преобразовать в число тесте `HelloWorld`? Если так, то, видимо, у вас оно не в том тестовом поле или тестовое поле не то или где-то вы ID напутали. В общем дело в невнимательности.